# Можно ли как то добавить в диалог открытия файла в WINAPI дополнительные кнопки?

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

[image]

Например в Visual Studio есть такой диалог для открытия проекта с двумя переключателями, есть ли какой то простой способ сделать подобное без написания всего диалога с нуля?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6093152/5045688

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Можно.
Для WinAPI используйте флажки в структуре OPENFILENAME, переопределяющие шаблон диалога (поле LPCTSTR lpTemplateName + флажок OFN_ENABLETEMPLATE в поле Flags) и добавляющие хук к обработчику сообщений (поле LPOFNHOOKPROC lpfnHook + флажок OFN_ENABLEHOOK в поле Flags). Однако есть некоторые ограничения именно для общих шаблонов выбора файла для чтения Open / записи SaveAS, в зависимости от того, используется ли старый стиль или новый стиль шаблона (флажок OFN_EXPLORER в поле Flags). В одном случае Вы можете только добавить свой шаблон к стандартному шаблону, а в другом полностью заменить его. Учтите, что идентификаторы ваших дополнительных элементов управления не должны совпадать с идентификаторами стандартных элементов.

Описание деталей этого можно почитать в MSDN в разделе [Customizing Common Dialog Boxes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646951%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Там же указано, в каких именно файлах можно посмотреть определение стандартных шаблонов, используемых в рамках ComDlg32 / Common Dialog Box Library.

Этот метод работает на системах, начиная с Windows 2000 / Windows Server 2000 и выше. Если нам достаточно поддержки Windows Vista / Windows Server 2008 и выше, мы пишем на С++, а не на С, то используем интерфейс [IFileDialogCustomize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775912%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) из [Common Item Dialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776913%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#api).

Comment: Common Dialog Box Library уже устарела. Не следует советовать ее в 2018.

Comment: Полностью согласен. Все зависит от требований по обратной совместимости. Если пишем под Windows Vista / Windows Server 2008 и выше, используем новый интерфейс из [Common Item Dialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776913%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), если хотим поддержки Windows 2000 / Windows Server 2000 и выше, пишем с использованием GetOpenFileName из [Common Dialog Box Library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645524%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Для этого служит интерфейс [`IFileDialogCustomize`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775912(v=vs.85).aspx). Этот интерфейс реализован в стандартных диалогах выбора файлов. Позволяет добавлять кнопки, переключатели, текстовые поля и т.п.